# please migrate this question

Tags: discussion

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu/9103299#9103299) question should be in this stack. is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't, and shouldn't really, migrate that question. First off:

Questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated. That question was asked way back in 2011, it is much too old now ;)

Second, the aforementioned question is on-topic on Stack Overflow, there is really no reason to migrate it here unless the OP had requested it (this would have to have happened before the deadline, see above). Quite a few SE sites overlap so the general policy when questions overlap several site's topic is to leave it where it was first asked, unless the OP wants otherwise.

One last note: We can't "take" questions from other sites, they have to send them to us, so this isn't the best place to ask for these migrations. That would be [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).